# Spring MVC RequestMapping not working on RestController

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I want to have a RestController-class with the base-mapping "/user" (so the different functions will have paths like "/user/add", "/user/remove" etc or use POST/GET etc)

This is the part that I don't understand and can't get to work:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/user")
  public Response login(Principal principal){
    //some output
  }
}
```

Expected behavior for this case would be that I can access my output under "/user". This works as expected.
Now if I modify it to the following (since all functions in this controller should have a path starting with "/user" this would be cleaner)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public Response login(Principal principal){
    //some output
  }
}
```

I get a 404-Error page and can't access "/user" anymore
All examples I have found use the same syntax (or sometimes @RequestMapping(path="/user") but that didn't work as well) and I don't know why it doesn't work.
Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use this code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@GetMapping("/")
public Response login(Principal principal){
//some output
 }
}
```

Then your url should have "/" at the end like "http://localhost:8080/user/"

I would just throw away "/" symbol from  @GetMapping("/") and left like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@GetMapping
public Response login(Principal principal){
//some output
 }
}
```

And if you need map get or post you can use like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@GetMapping("/add")
public SampleObj getJson() {
    return new SampleObj();
 }
}
```

It should work.